# What do you call the inner leaves of a tree?

Tags: word-choice

Like, there are leaves on the outside, and leaves on the inside which are usually protected from the elements.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is not enough research/information in the post to indicate that such a word even exists.

Comment: @TusharRaj If he knew that such a word even exists, he would probably know the word itself, too...

Comment: @Sprottenwels: Probably. Not necessarily. We get requests here where the asker _knows_ there is a word but can't place it. Good OPs even include what their reasearch turned up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there aren't any words to describe this.
Adhering to a phyllotaxy dictionary also doesn't yield good results.

You may want to use *'sheltered/shielded/inner foliage'* or *'inter-verduary so-and-so'* or even *'secluded leafage/foliage'*.

Capitalizing on the 'covered' aspect, by using adjectives like 'umbriferous' (Meaning: casting shade or shadow), in a different syntax as opposed to your sentence can also, if done right, yield the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that there is a single term for this but I might be wrong.

I'd suggest something like '*delicate foliage*', maybe with further circumscription.

> The tree's inner delicate foliage, protected from harms of any sort by the shrouding outer leaves

Answer (score 1):

•SHOOT:

"Shoot(s)", meaning emerging steam and embryonic leaves of a new plant, may be used.

•SPROUT:

A new growth on a plant whether from seeds or other parts is called 'SPROUT'It can be used as well.

•EAR:

At the simplest, "EAR" may have a chance